# Magento 2 - Change the Max height of the fotorama gallery

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, fotorama, fotorama-slider

In Magento 2, I changed the fotorama gallery to vertical. Now I want to limit either the maximum number of thumbnails that shows when the page loads or limit the height of the fotorama gallery.

As an example, if I have a product with 10 thumbnail images. I want the page to show 5 thumbnail images and the rest can be accessed using the arrows in the fotorama gallery.

Comment: you want to set 5 thumbnail images on fotorama gallery to vertical right?
(I mean set digit as statically or dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

You can place the file `view.xml` in your theme's `/etc` directory with contents like this:

```
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <media>
        <images module="Magento_Catalog">
            <image id="product_page_image_small" type="thumbnail">
                <width>93</width>
                <height>140</height>
            </image>
        </images>
    </media>
</view>
```

- By changing the width and height of the images, you can control how many will be displayed in the slider.